# Angular8: Error intercepting http response

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to intercept all the HttpResponse using angular interceptor as

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          // do stuff with response and headers you want
          event.body = event.body.data || event.body;
          console.log('event--->>>', event);
        }
        return event;      
      })
    );
```

but typescript gives an error

`ERROR in src/app/shared/interceptors/auth.interceptor.ts(35,17): error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'body' because it is a read-only property.`

What should I do to tackle this?

> NOTE: Cloning the object using `Object.assign` still gives the same error for new object.

Answer (score 1):

can't you reassign the variable like this :

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
  map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
    let returnValue = Object.assign({}, event);
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      // do stuff with response and headers you want
      returnValue.body = event.body.data || event.body;
      console.log('event--->>>', event);
    }
    return returnValue;      
  })
);
```

since you've reassigned the variable, you should be able to change it's body

EDIT : if you are sure you have the body property inside your object you can do the assignation like this

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
    map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        let returnValue = Object.assign({}, event);
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            // do stuff with response and headers you want
            returnValue.body = event['body'].data || event['body'];
            console.log('event--->>>', event);
        }
        return returnValue;
    );
```

Comment: `let returnValue = event` wont work, `returnValue` will be just anther reference to the `event`, so would result in same error.

Comment: if you use Object.assign you won't have any problem

Comment: yes, that can be done, or you can use `...` operator as well, but you should delete the `let returnValue = event` line as it is not correct.

Comment: I get error

Property 'body' does not exist on type '{ type: HttpEventType.Sent; } | { type: HttpEventType.ResponseHeader; headers: HttpHeaders; status: number; statusText: string; url: string; ok: boolean; } | { type: HttpEventType.UploadProgress | HttpEventType.DownloadProgress; loaded: number; total?: number; } | { ...; } | { ...; }'.
  Property 'body' does not exist on type '{ type: HttpEventType.Sent; }'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 1):

The `body` property of the `event` object is readonly, You cannot redefine / reassign it. What you could do, is copy the event into a newly created event modify the body of this event and then return this object.

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          // we use this syntax to deep copy the event. 
          // we don't want any reference to the previous event.
          const newEvent = {...event};
          // we edit the copied event. 
          newEvent.body = newEvent .body.data || newEvent .body;
          console.log('event--->>>', newEvent );
          // we need to return the new event.
          return newEvent
        }
        // nothing is happening, we are returning the event.
        return event;      
      })
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it using the event.clone method

```
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          let newEvent: HttpEvent<any>;
          // alter response here. maybe do the following
          newEvent = event.clone({
            // alter event params here
            body: event.body.data || event.body
          });
          return newEvent;
        }
      })
    );
```

Comment: This seams to be working fine but be careful, if your event is not an instance of `HttpResponse` it will be ignored since it's not returned from your interceptor.

Comment: I am sure my event has to be HttpResponse

Comment: then why are you validating it ?